# Printing a factorial from an integer

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am very new to functional programming. I wrote this program where the user can enter an integer and it will print the factorial. If the user enters a negative integer or not an integer at all, it'll give the user a second chance.

This doesn't feel very functional to me. How can I make this code more functional (esp. the main function)? Or is this just fine?

```
module Main where
import Data.Char

factorial :: Integer -> Integer
factorial 0 = 1
factorial n = product [1..n]

isIntegral :: String -> Bool
isIntegral [] = False
isIntegral st = all isDigit st

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter a non-negative integer:"
  numberStr <- getLine
  if isIntegral numberStr
    then do
      let number = read numberStr :: Integer
      if number < 0
        then do
          main
        else do
          putStrLn $ show $ factorial number
    else do
      main
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line `factorial 0 = 1` is redundant. The product of the empty list is already 1.

When writing a function that only works with strings (instead of arbitrary lists), I'd prefer to use `""` instead of `[]` to denote the empty string. This way it's more obvious we're dealing with strings.

Since your `isIntegral` function will return false for negative numbers (because `-` is not a digit), you should name it something like `isNaturalNumber` instead.

<s>Instead of applying `read` to the result of `getLine`, you can just use `readLn`.</s> (Edit: since in your latest revision you do error checking on the string before using `read`, this no longer applies). Likewise you can use `print` instead of `putStrLn` and `show`.

Instead of having multiple `$`s on the same line, it is usually preferred to combine `.`s and `$`s. However using `print` you only need `print $ factorial number` anyway.

There is no point in prefixing a single expression with `do`, so you should remove the `do`s from your `if` and `else`.

Also since your `isIntegral`/`isNaturalNumber` function already returns false for negative numbers, there's no need to check whether the result is negative after calling `read`, so you can get rid of the if-statement and the duplication of calling `main` recursively from two different places.

Comment: I have added error checking (see the updated question) so I guess I can't simply use `readLn` anymore. Is there a solution for that? Thanks for all the other tips!

Comment: @WTP: Yes, I noticed that. I adjusted my answer in response to your edit (and yes, with error checking it's no longer possible to use `readLn`).

Answer (score 3):

Reifying a few of sepp2k's suggestions:

```
module Main where
import Data.Char

factorial :: Integer -> Integer
factorial n = product [1..n]

isNat :: String -> Bool
isNat [] = False
isNat st = all isDigit st

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter a non-negative integer:"
  numberStr <- getLine
  if isNat numberStr
    then print . factorial . read $ numberStr
    else main
```

An alternate approach, use `Maybe`s:

```
module Main where
import Data.Char

factorial :: Integer -> Integer
factorial n = product [1..n]

parseNat :: String -> Maybe Integer
parseNat [] = Nothing
parseNat st | all isDigit st = Just $ read st
            | otherwise      = Nothing

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter a non-negative integer:"
  numberStr <- getLine
  case parseNat numberStr of
    Just num -> print $ factorial num
    Nothing  -> main
```

For different control flow, you might like `unless` and `when` from [Control.Monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#g:6).

Also, be aware of [hlint](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/hlint/), which can sometimes give you tips on being more Haskellish.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Haskell is pure functional language, so you can not write anything non-functional in it. However, some improvements can be made:

- Instead of making a custom check for `isIntegral` you can use the `reads` function, which is does the same thing as `read`, but instead of crashing returns the empty list on failure.
- Your program consists of two steps: reading a number and printing its factorial. However, the complicated control flow makes it difficult to see. You can make it more explicit.
- It is often beneficial to bring the amount of code involving `IO` to the minimum because IO is hard to reason about. You can extract the `IO`-free code into separate functions.

The last two "improvements" increase the code size in this case though, so they are not so useful here. Try writing a more complex program and concerns like this will become relevant.

```
factorial n = product [1..n]

readNumber :: String -> Maybe Integer
readNumber numberStr = case reads numberStr of
  [(number,"")] | number >= 0 -> Just number
  _ -> Nothing

getNumber :: IO Integer
getNumber = do
  putStrLn "Enter a non-negative integer:"
  numberStr <- getLine
  case readNumber numberStr of
    Nothing -> getNumber
    Just number -> return number

main :: IO ()
main = getNumber >>= print . factorial
```

Comment: I'd use a guard in readNumber: `[(number,"")] | number >= 0 -> ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider replacing `isIntegral` with an inline test:

```
...
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter a non-negative integer:"
  numberStr <- getLine
  if not (null numberStr) && all isDigit numberStr
    ...
```

It's hard to explain, both concisely and correctly, what `isIntegral` (or as some suggested, `isNat` or `isNaturalNumber`) does.  Sure, you can say it tests if the string contains a non-negative integer.  But does it accept hexadecimal syntax?  How does it treat octals?

On the other hand, perhaps the definition of `isIntegral` can be based on purpose, rather than function:

```
-- | Test if the string is a valid, non-negative integer that can be parsed
-- with 'read'.
isIntegral :: String -> Bool
isIntegral [] = False
isIntegral st = all isDigit st
```

By this interpretation, keeping `isIntegral` separate makes it easier to extend later (e.g. to allow hexadecimal syntax, which `read :: String -> Integer` accepts).  It's a matter of fixing a standalone function, rather than modifying code buried in a procedure with broader scope (namely, `main`).

However, `isIntegral`'s definition assumes that the caller calls `read` (or similar) after validating the input with `isIntegral`.  It would be simpler to do the reading and validation in one function.  See the `readNumber` function in [Rotsor's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/8044/2672), which uses [`reads`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:reads) and a [guard](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Control_structures#Guards) to accomplish this.

### Playing with point-free

Let's see if we can make this more concise:

```
isIntegral :: String -> Bool
isIntegral [] = False
isIntegral st = all isDigit st
```

Or, put another way:

```
isIntegral st = not (null st) && all isDigit st
```

We can express it in [point-free](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree) style (i.e. eliminate variables using combinators like `.`, `flip`, `uncurry`, etc.):

```
isIntegral = liftA2 (&&) (not . null) (all isDigit)
```

Yes, this is longer and more cryptic.  However, with a little practice, it's easy to see that it's combining two predicates, `not . null` and `all isDigit`, with the `&&` operator.  Since `&&` doesn't like functions as arguments, the noisy `liftA2` ([from Control.Applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2)) is applied to `&&` to combine predicates.

Although I would say point-free is overkill here, it's good to practice using it.  Here are a couple examples where point-free does make things more concise (in my opinion):

```
-- Read two lines, and combine their values with (+)
addLines :: IO Integer
addLines = (+) <$> readLn <*> readLn

-- Call "hPutStrLn msg" on each Handle in the list.
--
-- Unfortunately, `hPutStrLn` takes the Handle argument first, so we have to
-- flip it to use it like we want.
broadcast :: String -> [Handle] -> IO ()
broadcast = mapM_ . flip hPutStrLn
```

Learning to write in point-free style can help you write programs faster.  Here's a script I wrote recently that takes a list of file names, and prints lines present in every file:

```
import Data.List (foldl1')
import System.Environment

import qualified Data.Set as S

main :: IO ()
main = getArgs
   >>= mapM (fmap (S.fromList . lines) . readFile)
   >>= mapM_ putStrLn . S.toList . foldl1' S.intersection
```